# Excel VBA Collections and Custom Data Types

Tags: excel, vba, collections, types

I'm trying to learn how to create a custom data type, then use that with a collection.  I solved the problem another way, but this started with a timesheet report I was automating.  I originally wanted a 2 dimensional array with varying data types.  When I couldn't do that, some research led to the idea of a collection of custom data types.  However the examples I have found keep pushing me to create a class.  I am not yet comfortable with that and it seems like this should be doable.  Here is kind of what I am a looking for (I started with an example I found on this site):

```
Option Explicit

'***** User defined type
Public Type MyType
  MyInt As Integer
  MyString As String
  MyDoubleArr(2) As Double
End Type

Public ColThings As Collection

Sub CollectionTest()
  Dim x As Integer
  Dim vrecord As MyType

  For x = 1 To 4
      vrecord.MyInt = x
      vrecord.MyString = "Matt"
      vrecord.MyDoubleArr(0) = x + 5
      vrecord.MyDoubleArr(1) = x + 6
      vrecord.MyDoubleArr(2) = x + 7
      ColThings.Add vrecord
  Next x

  For x = 1 To 4
     Debug.Assert vrecord.MyInt & " - " & vrecord.MyString & " - " &   vrecord.MyDoubleArr(0) & ", " & vrecord.MyDoubleArr(1) & ", " & vrecord.MyDoubleArr(0)
  Next x
End Sub
```

The error I get is:
Compile Error:
"Only user-defined types defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions"

I am not a novice with VBA, but I am trying to make the next step.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My understanding is (and I may certainly be mistaken here) that you cannot add a user-defined type into a collection, which itself is an object.   I think you will have to create a class, instantiate it, then add it to your collection.  You may be able to use an array instead of a collection to store your UDT though.

Comment: I'm unclear on why you are looping through *vrecord* and not *ColThings* at the end of your procedure.

Comment: Stop *practicing it wrong*; create a class as your guides are recommending, and start *practicing it right*.  Practicing your bad habits so strenuously, early on, will simply make it harder to break them later.

Comment: This weekend is my personal "class on classes".  I am jumping into at the house.  I do not intend to keep trying to go around things I am unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 4):

I took a stab at it, ultimately I am not sure if this is what you want, but if you don't want to make a class then the only other option I can see is to store your types in an array instead of a collection.  To my knowledge (please correct me if I am wrong) *you cannot add a user-defined type to a collection*, you must create it as a class, instantiate an object of that class, then add that to the collection.

Instead I declared the array `Records()` of `MyType` and added each `MyType` to that array.

```
Option Explicit

'***** User defined type
Public Type MyType
  MyInt As Integer
  MyString As String
  MyDoubleArr(2) As Double
End Type

Public ColThings As Collection

Sub CollectionTest()
  Dim x As Integer
  Dim Records() As MyType
  Dim vrecord As MyType

  For x = 1 To 4
      vrecord.MyInt = x
      vrecord.MyString = "Matt"
      vrecord.MyDoubleArr(0) = x + 5
      vrecord.MyDoubleArr(1) = x + 6
      vrecord.MyDoubleArr(2) = x + 7
      ReDim Preserve Records(x)
      Records(x) = vrecord
  Next x

  For x = 1 To 4
     Debug.Print Records(x).MyInt & " - " & Records(x).MyString & " - " & Records(x).MyDoubleArr(0) & ", " & Records(x).MyDoubleArr(1) & ", " & Records(x).MyDoubleArr(0)
  Next x

End Sub
```

I believe that is *similar* to what you want to accomplish.  I haven't attempted the class method yet as you said you were not quite ready for that, but that would be a very good exercise in my humble opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I may have very well been led astray by something I read on the MSDN ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1ad18x6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)).  That discussion was about using collections with non-object data.  On reviewing that post, it appears that it is for visual basic not VBA.  I agree this is likely a good jumping in point for me to work with classes.  The array of the User-Defined-Type would have been the answer to my original problem.  But now this is a learning exercise.  Thank you again.

Comment: Yes I believe you have been unintentionally misled.  It's happens between `VB` `VBScript` and `VBA` but I've been doing a bit of research (piqued my curiosity) and every source I found says adding user-defined types to a collection isn't supported in `VBA`.