# Late Binding a UDT in a form module to pass as a parameter

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an access database and I'm attempting to write some VBA to increase automation.

I have a module I've entitled `Global Variables` which I've successfully used to define global constants (file paths etc) and a module `ReportCode` which has two main subrouties, one to run a query with `ADODB` (scraping form params where needed - returning a recordset), and a second which takes this record set and writes the data out to an excel template.

Given I may want to have multiple queries write to multiple tabs I thought the best way was to define a `ExportDocument` object to contain common parameters and a `OrgReport` object, containing query and tab specific parameters - then gather multiple `OrgReport` objects in a collection.

I'd hope to then pass just these two parameters into the main subroutine. This turns out to be a pain in VBA (or at least compared to ruby!).

Here you can see how I've defined by custom objects

```
Option Private Module

' Define Custom Doc Object
Public Type ExportDocument
    TeamName As String
    TemplatePath As String
    SaveName As String
    SavePath As String
End Type

' Define Custom Report Object
Public Type OrgReport
    Query As String
    Fields As Variant
    Sheet As String
    StartCol As Integer
    StartRow As Integer
    Headers As Boolean
End Type
```

And here is the code in my form which then called an additional module which does the heavy lifting - I know that part works because it did before I tried to go all OOP on this...

```
Private Sub my_report_from_form_Click()

    ' Prep Query Inputs
    Dim TeamX_Report As OrgReport

    TeamX_Report.Query = "qry_TeamReporting Query"
    TeamX_Report.Sheet = "RawData"
    TeamX_Report.StartCol = 1
    TeamX_Report.StartRow = 2
    TeamX_Report.Headers = True
    TeamX_Report.Fields = Nothing

    ' Prep Document Inputs
    Dim Teamx_Doc As ExportDocument

    Teamx_Doc.TeamName = "MyTeam"
    Teamx_Doc.TemplatePath = strReportTemplatePath & "MyTeam.xltm"
    Teamx_Doc.SaveName = ""
    Teamx_Doc.SavePath = strReportSavePath & Teamx_Doc.TeamName

    ' Init and set collection for CHAIN reports
    Dim TeamReports As New Collection
    TeamReports .Add Item:=TeamX_Report, Key:=TeamX_Report.Query

    Call export_data_dump(Teamx_Doc, TeamReports)
End Sub
```

This gives me the issue of:

> [Only public user defined types defined in public object modules can be
>   used as parameters or return types for public procedures of class
>    modules or as fields of public user defined types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251483.aspx)

Following advice [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1.aspx) I changed

```
Dim Teamx_Doc As ExportDocument
```

to

```
Teamx_Doc = CreateObject("ExportDocument")
```

But alas now i get

> Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object VBA

All references to this problem seem to be related to calling code from the `Word.`, `Excel.` or `Outlook.` codebases, so perhaps I'm just missing a prefix for my own module stored within my database?

Best lead I've found is this [one](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=730446), which seems to suggest there's deeper issues with what i'm trying to do, or that i may get around parts by calling `Friend`, though I'm lost to where and how.

Is there a way I can late bind my UDT Objects within my form code, stash one in a collection then pass both to a subroutine that will be able to grab params from the first 'Doc' object and then iterate through the second 'report' object?

VBA >_<

Comment: Have you tried removing "Option private module"

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason I can see why this doesn't work:

```
Dim Teamx_Doc As ExportDocument
```

Especially if you're not getting an error on line

```
Dim TeamX_Report As OrgReport
```

I've used custom Public Types before - no need for CreateObject

Though the docs seem to say it's just fine, can you try removing the

```
Option Private Module
```

Comment: Initially me either, but I think that's an example of early binding which my error message says won't work!

Comment: It's not early binding if your defining the Public Type in your own code. Early bindng refers more to setting a Reference to an external DLL or ActiveX object

Comment: Humm... Ok so perhaps it's because I'm trying to keep my code organised in different modules... I'm try removing option private module from there first then copy all into the same. Module at the top... Not sure why it won't work thought, my constants are!

Comment: You don't need to copy all the code into one module. Just make your constants and functions inside each module as PRIVATE if you don't want them seen outside your module. Any shared functions or constants should be labelled as PUBLIC - I think that's the default

Comment: Ok so... upon a closer inspection (and with everything set to public all the way down the stack) I believe the problem emerges from when I try to add my object to a collection. Debug stops at `TeamReports .Add Item:=TeamX_Report, Key:=Teamx_Doc.Query` with `TeamX_Report` highlighted, then throwing the only public...  It it perhaps more to do with how I am adding objects to a collection?

Comment: [This post](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?599355-RESOLVED-Addin-a-user-defined-type-to-a-collection#post_3703363) seems to suggest what I'm doing isn't possible.

Comment: It looks like you might have something mixed up on that line - I'm not sure what you're trying so I'm just guessing, but it doesn't look like `Key:=Teamx_Doc.Query` is defined - but maybe you want to use `Key:=TeamX_Report.Query` - or what exactly are you trying to pass as second parameter?

Comment: Good spot, sorry that was a stupid typo - was trying to use more general variable names than what's actually in my code. The idea is to automatically spit out data into excel templates. The `ExportDocument` Object holds paths and params for the file a `TeamX_Report` object should hold details of the query, excel tab and how the data is to be pasted - of which there might be a few per sheet, so i has hoping to put them in a collection, pass that through to by `sub` and then iterate within the code. As the query name is always unique - hoped i could use that as a key!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is kinda misleading. You simply can't put variables with an User-defined Type into a collection.

**Option 1**: Use an **array** instead. This actually sounds like it would work well for what you want to do.

**Option 2**: Create a **class module** instead of an UDT for `OrgReport`. Then instantiate objects of that class, those you can add to a collection.

See
[Excel VBA Collections and Custom Data Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130439/excel-vba-collections-and-custom-data-types)
and
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/16849-adding-user-defined-types-collection.html

Comment: Option 1 looks promising, many thanks. Will do a bit more reading on arrays and give it a go!